# Google App Script - Web App - Get Active Sheet Name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I have a Google Apps Script published as a WebApp. In the script, I would like to be able to select the active sheet and get the sheet name.

For example, I have a spreadsheet with two tabs: Tab1 and Tab2. I am currently viewing Tab2 in the UI.

When I run the following code I expect thisSheet = "Tab2". Instead it is always equal to "Tab1".

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
var thisSheet = sheet.getName();
```

Keep in mind I will not know what the name of the sheet will be. I realize that it is an issue of context running from the web app, because when I run the function from within the ScriptEditor it performs as expected. Is there any workaround while executing this code from a web app?

Comment: Could you clarify why do you need to access the spreadsheet in context of a deployed web application? Knowing what is the expected behaviour when a web app is accessed will help us think of a solution

Comment: I'm extracting the tab name to plug in to an API call from the webapp. Is that useful?

Comment: George, could you also provide info on how the flow is triggered - is it an `onOpen()` / `onEdit()` trigger, etc? Basically, in what context `getActiveSpreadsheet()` is called?

Comment: getActiveSpreadsheet() is called from doGet. Would calling it from onOpen or onEdit make a difference?

Comment: When you access the web-app, spreadsheet might not even be open. Where will the active sheet come from then?

Comment: George, following up on TheMaster's inquiry, you *can* return reference to the active spreadsheet if your web app is deployed from a bound script, but it won't be able to determine whose ui to reference in the first place. What I asked earlier is - why do you need to get an *active* sheet from a 3P service?

Comment: So the architecture of this web app is that I created one core script that listens for a response from an API. Then to distribute this functionality I make a copy of the original spreadsheet and script and share with a colleague. To initiate a function call it must be done through the UI, so a spreadsheet will always be open when this code is run. This is probably a hacky method but its got me 95% of the way to what I want to do.

Comment: Still doesn't explain Why web app? How about trying a sidebar or modal dialog?

Comment: George, please, could you explain what do you mean when you say "this functionality"? We are still usure what is going on there: 1. What makes an API call in the first place? 2. Can this API return a response immediately when you make a call to it, assuming it is done via `UrlFetchApp`? 3. What happens script-wise after the response is received?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple web app:

```
function doGet() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var html=Utilities.formatString('Process Complete:ActiveSheet: %s',ss.getActiveSheet().getName());
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html);
}
```

When I have the spreadsheet open and I run the webapp it always returns the name of the leftmost sheet.  This is the sheet you get when you open a Spreadsheet on the server `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheets()[0]`;

Comment: I've never thought about it before but I can't think of way right now.